# ClassNotFoundException with Spring sample projects

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I'm trying to run the most up to date spring sample projects in eclipse but i'm always getting ClassNotFoundException. (For example with spring-mvc-showcase project)

Environment:

- Ubuntu 12.04, 64bit (same problem with 13.10)
- openjdk-7-jdk, openjdk-7-jre installed
- Eclipse kepler Java EE version, STS installed.

Steps:

- I make a new project: Spring/Import Spring Getting Started Content
- When all the dependencies loaded, right click on the project name / Run As / Run On Server: J2EE Preview at localhost

Jetty output:

> 2014-01-16 20:13:01.241:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.10.v20130312
>   2014-01-16 20:13:02.905:WARN:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:Could not instantiate listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1517)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitListener(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1839)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:80)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:67)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1219)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-01-16 20:13:02.931:WARN:oejs.Holder:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:97)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:91)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-01-16 20:13:02.932:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED httpMethodFilter: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
>   javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:91)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-01-16 20:13:02.933:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/petclinic,[file:/home/szilard/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/spring-petclinic/, jar:file:/home/szilard/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/spring-petclinic/WEB-INF/lib/jquery-2.0.3-1.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/szilard/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/spring-petclinic/WEB-INF/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.jar!/META-INF/resources/, jar:file:/home/szilard/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/spring-petclinic/WEB-INF/lib/bootstrap-2.3.0.jar!/META-INF/resources/]},/home/szilard/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/spring-petclinic
>   javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:91)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-01-16 20:13:03.416:WARN:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:Could not instantiate listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1517)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitListener(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1839)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:80)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:67)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:332)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1219)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-01-16 20:13:03.431:WARN:oejs.Holder:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:100)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:79)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:97)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:91)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-01-16 20:13:03.432:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED csrfFilter: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
>   javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:91)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-01-16 20:13:03.432:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/spring-mvc-showcase,file:/home/szilard/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/spring-mvc-showcase/},/home/szilard/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/spring-mvc-showcase
>   javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:104)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:91)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:719)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1221)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:710)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:454)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:280)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.run(PreviewStarter.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.internal.PreviewStarter.main(PreviewStarter.java:29)
>   2014-01-16 20:13:03.485:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned the [Spring MVC Showcase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase) as the project you are trying to run. I recommend running from the terminal before trying to build and run in Eclipse. This eliminates any issues you may have with your Eclipse environment. The readme on the github page says to run the following command:

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

The app will build and deploy to a Tomcat 7 instance. You'll see this in the terminal. Once it starts, you can access the showcase app at the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-showcase/
```

I just tried these steps and was able to successfully view the showcase app in my browser. After you verify that you can run the app from the terminal, then you can try deploying it to Tomcat inside of Eclipse.

Comment: Your advice worked, it runs now if i run it with maven. Now i have to figure out what is the problem with eclipse...

Comment: @Andrea When i load the project to eclipe, it says: Description Resource Path Location Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (execution: default, phase: process-sources) pom.xml /spring-mvc-showcase line 271 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

Comment: Try to import in Eclipse as an "Existing Maven Project" and point it to the folder where the pom.xml is located. When I do this, I'm able to drag the project to an Apache Tomcat 7 server config, then run it. I'm using the Spring Tool Suite Eclipse distribution.

Comment: It doesen't work, here are my screenshots: http://tinypic.com/r/1hxlxg/5 http://tinypic.com/r/2v35t2q/5

Comment: Looks like you need the AspectJ Development Tools. Downloading from the Eclipse Marketplace is probably the easiest way to install it.

Comment: Ok, its a problem with eclipse maven plugin. With eclipse Juno, it works. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the project are under maven.

pack the project using the follow command.

mvn clean package

than try run again.

Comment: This also works. I can build a war file, and run it in tomcat7. But still problems with eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the nature of your project...if that is a a
maven project you should

- have those dependencies in compile
- have war as packaging

The pom editor in eclipse is your friend for making sure both points

If is a wtp project the build path settings change between eclipse versions

However...the final result must be the same: check the built war and make sure those libraries are in WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score -1):

If the project is not built by maven and is a simple eclipse dynamic web project, try doing this

If exists, delete the .snap file located in the directory `<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources`

After deleting this file, you could start Eclipse with no problem.

If not, delete `tmp0` (name may vary to tmp) folder in the following directory `<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core`

If there is any problem on deleting this folder then restart your eclipse then again delete that folder.